# How to add a subscript in an existing PDF files by programming in C?

Tags: c, pdf-generation

Some ebooks have copyright-related subscripts on each page. I want to know is there anyway to do this job by programming? Specifically speacking, in C programming language.

It is impossible for them to add this manually, so I think there should be some smart method, but I failed to get any userful information from google.

Comment: What technology/method are you using to generate PDFs using C?

Comment: for that you need to understand the file format of pdf file and make some program to add that subscript.

Answer (score 0):

[PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Technical_foundations) is a set of structures applied to a subset of the [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) language. There are a few [libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Development_libraries) that should help you manipulate PDF files. You will probably need to know a lot about the formatting of your documents to make this work.

Comment: could you please give some hint about these libraries? google gives no useful information.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation on the libraries yourself.